# What are some good SharePoint security resources?

Tags: security, sharepoint

I've got a SharePoint application and I'm sad to say that in my SharePoint-induced excitement, I ignored a lot of the security concerns I should have been paying more attention to.  Though we didn't before, now we actually *need* granular security, so I need to get educated.  I'm mostly interested in how to best create groups and add users to those groups.  We have a single main site collection and a couple dozen subsites under that collection.  How can I best create a granular security world where I can independently assign rights to each of these subsites?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To have permissions vary at the "sub site" level which is the SPWeb object in object model terms you need to **enable unique permission for the site**.

A good article outlining the permission hierarchy in SharePoint 2007 can be found on the office web site [About controlling access to sites and site content](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointtechnology/HA101001441033.aspx)

In my experience if you are able to use permission inheritance over granular security it's much less hassle to manage.

**Breaking site permission inheritance**

- Click "**People and groups**"
- Click "**Site permissions**"
- From the actions menu in the list click "**Edit Permissions**"

[http://blog.richfinn.net/content/binary/WindowsLiveWriter/InstallandConfiguretheCommunityKitforSha_E660/image_3.png http://blog.richfinn.net/content/binary/WindowsLiveWriter/InstallandConfiguretheCommunityKitforSha_E660/image_3.png](http://blog.richfinn.net/content/binary/WindowsLiveWriter/InstallandConfiguretheCommunityKitforSha_E660/image_3.png)

**Other references**

- [SharePoint 2007: Permissions, permissions, permissions.](http://dattard.blogspot.com/2007/02/sharepoint-2007-permissions-permissions.html)
- [SharePoint 2007 SiteGroups - part 1 - the basics](http://www.sharepointblogs.com/tonstegeman/archive/2006/10/14/sharepoint-2007-sitegroups-part-1-the-basics.aspx)